# Using Tags – Question from former CVS user

Tags: git, gitlab, cvs

I’m in the process of moving our CVS database over to Git.  The move requires me to rethink some configurations and procedures.  One of the challenges that I’m working with is that tags applies to the complete repository in Git while in CVS they can apply to a single file.

I have used CVS mainly for source code, but I have also used it for other types of files.  One application that I have used CVS for and that I now want to use Git for, is version control of drawings for part numbers.

In CVS I had one module with a few hundred subfolders.  Each subfolder contained drawings for one part.  I would tag each folder with the revision of the drawings for that part.  There was no correlation between the revisions of the drawings for the different parts.

One solution to accomplish the same thing in Git would be to make a few hundred repositories, one for each part, but this has some drawbacks.  For example, it would be difficult to clone the complete part library/module to my local computer.  I think that that I would have to clone each repository manually to do this.

Is there a better solution for setting something like this up in Git?  Is there a different type of tag that I can apply to only a selection of files?  Is there a way to clone all repositories with one command?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Git sounds like a poor fit here, since it's primarily concerned with an entire code base, rather than individual items. You might want to look into document management systems - sound more suited to your use case.

Answer (score 1):

> I think that that I would have to clone each repository manually ....

You *would* have to clone each repository.

You need not do this *manually*.  Git uses, internally, a scripting command language, and hence all Git installations have one.  (In many systems you already have it: "the shell" ([shell](/questions/tagged/shell)) or `/bin/sh`, or sometimes [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).)  Then all you need is a list of repositories to clone, plus a tiny bit of script:

```
for i in $(cat repo-list); do git clone ${baseurl}/$i; done
```

In general, once you have a repository, there's never any need to re-clone: you just keep the repository around and run `git fetch` on it as appropriate, if and when someone has updated the repository from which this clone was made.  So the loop above is not all that useful, but:

```
for i in $(cat repo-list); do (cd $i && git fetch); done
```

is more useful.  Note that this uses the same repo list.

You *can* also use submodules here, with a superproject that consists of nothing but a list of submodules, but that doesn't seem appropriate.  You could use something like Google's [repo tool](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/), which seems aimed at managing many loosely-related repositories like this.  (I have not used this tool myself.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I think that using the script may be a solution for us.

You are right, the fetch script will be more useful.  The clone script could be used to set up a new user to work with the repositories, but that would not be very often.

I looked at the submodules but if I’m not mistaking, these are pointers to specific commits of external repositories.  This would make them a little bit difficult to use, because I think that what I want is for them to follow the head of the master branch.

For right now I think that the script will work better.